# App crashes while Firebase receiving data is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Iam using firebase Realtime database to retreive user based data. there is some set of datas. Everything is fine while all the strings have values. But issue is sometimes, some data values will be empty for some users, while its empty, app is getting crashed. which means if any of object value is null, app is getting crashed. How can i solve this.Is there anyway to avoid this if value is null?. please advise

```
 reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Monthlypayment").child(user.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String name =dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String paymentstatus =dataSnapshot.child("paymentstatus").getValue().toString();
                String dueamount =dataSnapshot.child("dueamount").getValue().toString();
                String lastreceiptno =dataSnapshot.child("lastreceiptno").getValue().toString();
                String lastpaiddate =dataSnapshot.child("lastpaiddate").getValue().toString();
                String lastpaidamount =dataSnapshot.child("lastpaidamount").getValue().toString();
                String lastpaiddetails =dataSnapshot.child("lastpaiddetails").getValue().toString();
                Name.setText(name);
                Paymentstatus.setText(paymentstatus);
                Dueamount.setText(dueamount);
                Lastreceiptno.setText(lastreceiptno);
                Lastpaiddate.setText(lastpaiddate);
                Lastpaidamount.setText(lastpaidamount);
                Lastpaiddetails.setText(lastpaiddetails);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Monthly_Payment_Details.this,"Error loading data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hello Irfan, keep in mind that **Firebase removes the key if its value is set to ""**. So, if you mean by `null`/`empty` that you set node value to "", then the entire node will be removed and no key will be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get children count and if it is not zero then loop for children or access child.

```
int x=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
if(x>0)
{
   //TODO
}
else 
{
    //print null key
}
```

if does not know key and want to loop then:

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists())
{
for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
{
if(ds.child("name").exists())
String x=ds.child("name").getValue().toString();
}
}
```

Hope it removes your doubt.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if any object is null like this

```
if (dataSnapshot.exists())

if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("age"))

if (dataSnapshot.child("name").exists())
```

Comment: No user exists. Also toast message getting displayed user logged in successfuly(which is after getting UID child).

Comment: Check the the answer again